# Why do I need to call std::move on a temporary dynamic_bitset?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, boost-dynamic-bitset, xvalue

I'm telling a longwinded backstory here because, in addition to a direct answer, I'd like to know if my reasoning which led into this situation was correct.

I have a function taking a `dynamic_bitset<>` argument (from [Boost.dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)).
Say it looks like this.

```
void foo(boost::dynamic_bitset<> db) {
    // do stuff
}
```

It so happens that it's only ever called with temporaries, built from the constructor, as in `foo(boost::dynamic_bitset<>{5}.set())` (to call with a 5-bit bitset with all bits set).

My bitsets only have a small number of bits (fewer than 32). So at first, I thought "I'll just pass it by value; the copy is smaller than a pointer." But then I thought "It's dynamic, so it must allocate space on the heap. I want to avoid unnecessary allocations and frees."

So, I could make it

```
void foo(const boost::dynamic_bitset<>& db);
```

But a reference is a pointer, and a dynamic_bitset (presumably) has a pointer to its data, so then using `db` within `foo` would go through two levels of indirection, which seems dumb. Clearly the best way would be to copy the pointer to the data into `foo`, without reallocating and copying the data on the heap.

"Aha!" I say. "Surely this is what move semantics are for." So, I change the signature to

```
void foo(boost::dynamic_bitset<>&& db);
```

But then, calling `foo(boost::dynamic_bitset<>{5}.set())` gives a compiler error, `cannot bind 'boost::dynamic_bitset<>' lvalue to 'boost::dynamic_bitset<>&&'`.
I must instead call
`foo(std::move(boost::dynamic_bitset<>{5}.set()))`
and then everything works.

**Why do I need to call std::move?**
This seems like it's clearly an xvalue (a temporary about to expire), doesn't it?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the what `set` is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#synopsis):

```
dynamic_bitset& set();
```

`set()` returns an lvalue.

In general, if a function returns by value, or by rvalue reference:

```
dynamic_bitset   set();
dynamic_bitset&& set();
```

then the expression `set()` is an rvalue (in the first case a prvalue, and in the second an xvalue).  However because in the actual code `set()` returns an lvalue reference, the expression `set()` is an lvalue.

[category values http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/value-categories.svg](http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/value-categories.svg)

Comment: See, this confuses me, because I thought the result of a function call which isn't assigned to anything is always an xvalue. The canonical example for move semantics always seems to be `takemove( foo() )`, where the return type of `foo()` isn't discussed: the result is a temporary with no name, hence an xvalue. Are you saying that this works only if `foo()` does not return a reference?

Comment: @Kundor:  Updated answer to hopefully clarify.